# porter stemming algorithm implementation question?

Tags: c++, algorithm, porter-stemmer

I am trying to implement porter stemming algorithm but i am stuck at this point:

> Step 1b
>
> ```
> (m>0) EED -> EE                    feed      ->  feed
>                                    agreed    ->  agree
> (*v*) ED  ->                       plastered ->  plaster
>                                    bled      ->  bled
> (*v*) ING ->                       motoring  ->  motor
>                                    sing      ->  sing
> ```

Isn't the m of feed equal 1?  feed >> [c]vvc[] >>[c]vc[].

If it was so why didn't he convert feed to fee
i know it is wrong ,can any one clear that up?

you can check the original algorithim here http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/def.txt

thanks

Comment: FWIW, the Porter algorithm is already implemented in C as part of the "Snowball" library: http://snowball.tartarus.org/download.php

Comment: i know but i am implementing it for fun ,thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m of 'feed' is indeed 1. Yet, you need to re-read the document carefully. The m in the condition refers to the measure of the stem, that is you need to calculate in **after** the replacement. In your case to check if `feed -> fee` is valid, you calculate m(fee) = 0, hence you don't do the replacement.

Also thanks for the algorithm! It was interesting!